# Relationship between Phase Velocity and Velocity Factor

Tags: speed-of-light, velocity, phase-velocity

According to Wikipedia, the [Velocity Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor), is the ratio of the speed at which a wavefront passes through a medium to the speed of light in a vacuum.
While the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) is the rate at which a wave propagates in some medium.

To me, these two quantities seem to represent the same thing, apart from the normalization factor of the speed of light. Am I right, or am I missing something?